# TableViewController navigation bar title not bold

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

In my storyboard, the title of the navigation bar in the TableViewController is in bold by default (there are no options to change it). However, when I run the app, both in the simulator and on an iPhone 6S, the title is **not** in bold. The two screenshots below will show the difference. I did not find any settings to change the font in the interface builder. I am not sure that it was incorrect before updating the environment to iOS 10. No code is changing anything visual, everything is done in the interface builder

[image: Interface Builder]

[image: Simulator]

Answer (score 0):

try

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = 
[NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "your-bold-font", size: 21)!]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a label and add it to your navigationItem:

```
let title = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 7, width: 200, height: 30))
title.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
title.textColor = UIColor.white
title.text = "Test heading"
title.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)

let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: deviceHelper.screenWidth / 2, y: 0, width: 200, height: 44))
titleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
titleView.addSubview(title)
```